# Execute Linux script which redirects output to a file which is not present in path

Tags: linux

In linux box i have 2 users A and B.

A user has the following scripts under path below-These scripts can be run by only A
        `/lsa/sas/bnt/start.sh`
        `/lsa/sas/bnt/stop.sh`

Now i want to run these commands under B user.
So what i do is under B user

`$pbrun su - A /lsa/sas/bnt/stop.sh`

so this will login using pbrun as A ,go to that path execute that stop.sh script.

Now to run start.sh,the content inside start.sh is

`java -jar bnt.jar > ./logs/start.log`

means after running jar it will send output to start.log which is residing under `(/lsa/sas/bnt/logs/start.log)`  these all folders are already exist under User A.

If i want to run start.sh under A i can go into `cd /lsa/sas/bnt/` then do a start.sh and it works fine,it will run jar and redirect output to log file which resides in path.

But when i run the same command as B user - it says

`( [B@hostname ~]$ pbrun su - A /lsa/sas/bnt/start.sh
Starting the application...
/lsa/sas/bnt/start.sh: line 10: ./logs/start.log: No such file or directory)`

so here we dont have that logs/start.log in the path? How do I include that file here,so that i can run the script?

Comment: Make sure user B has `rw` permission on `./logs/start.log`. User B must be in the `group` that has `rw` permission on the file and in the group that has `r_x` permission to each directory above it.

Comment: `./logs/start.log` is a relative path. Perhaps make it an absolute path in the `start.sh` script. Or... add `cd /lsa/sas/bnt` to the beginning of your `start.sh` script so the relative path is pointing to the right location.

Comment: @David- I have set chmod 777 on logs and start.log. Still doesnot work. I added User B to the groups to each directory aove it. Still it fails with same error.

Comment: @JNevill- Hi, I can run the same script under user A, but as iam running under User B this way -`pbrun su - A /lsa/sas/bnt/start.sh` at the command line, it stops till /bnt/ and runs the script but script needs /logs/start.log to redirect output and as in the command line we have not specified path for /logs/start.log it cant find the files and throws the error. Any suggestions would be helpful to me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user5871215 pay close attention to the *directory* permissions above it (all of them). `B` must have at minimum `r_x` permission at every level above (the `x` or execute-bit controls whether a user has "*descent*" permission into the directory) So even if you have `drwxr_xr__` for each directory above, if `B` isn't in the *group* owning the directories above `B` will *not* have access to the files.

Comment: @David- Iam afraid I have all the permissions for directories above it.I really dono what am i missing. But my question is, as i run the command `pbrun su - A /lsa/sas/bnt/start.sh` this way . How can it access the log/start.log file as it is not residing in the path of the command we gave ?Isn't that the reason it says file or directory not found?